# Editing .vimrc file to make 'set ft=python' a default setting and something more

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, spf13vim

I am a new comer to the vim world, and I have just installed spf13-vim for a quick start. Apart from that I have not touched my .vimrc file.

I mainly use vim to write some python scripts on a remote server, so I have to type 'set ft=python' each time I open a file using vim. I am wondering if it's possible to edit my .vimrc file to make python a default choice of vim.

Another confusing thing is that each time I type a blank in vim, it shows a inverted question mark on my vim screen. I think it's because of some mismatch in file encoding, but I have no more idea about it.

I know it's a stupid question, but right now I can't solve it myself. Any help is appreciated.

## Edit:

I have solved the problem of setting python default by write 'set ft=python' to my .vimrc file. (I didn't know contents in .vimrc are commands in vim) But I still don't know how to eliminate the inverted question mark when I typed a blank char, even after I do some search.

Comment: Did you do any [research](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Vim)?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I have solved the problem of setting python default by write 'set ft=python' to my .vimrc file. (I didn't know contents in .vimrc are commands in vim) But I still don't know how to eliminate the inverted question mark when I typed a blank char, even after I do some search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the buffer you're editing from the start, don't forget the `:filetype plugin` in your `.vimrc` and then things will work correctly.

In any way having `:set ft=whatever` in your `.vimrc` is twice wrong. First it'll apply to all new sessions opened without a file. Moreover it'll only apply to the first buffer. I.e. it won't work with `:new`.